# Move to a specific element while css-scale is enabled using jquery ui draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am working with a jquery timeline project using jquery ui draggable.  The timeline width is 6900px wide.  The initial view of this timeline has a css-scale set to 0.6 (for a more zoomed-out version of the timeline - keep in mind the timeline width still stays the same).

Every "event" on the timeline has a css left property set. e.g. Event 1 (at the beginnning of the timeline) has a css left set to 0px, Event 2 has a css left set to 150px, etc. (increments of 150px).

Every event also has a specific ID set to it.  The Problem I have is when I need to browse/navigate to a specific event on the timeline, the css-scale property on the timeline seems to be confusing me.

By navigating/browsing to the event, I mean to set the timeline's css left property to the relevant Event I want to navigate/browse to, but failed a couple of times as the css left I set i to seems to be wrong.

Here is my try:

```
var rightStart = $('#timeline a').nextAll(".event_missed:first").parent().css('left').replace('px', '');
    var rightSide = Math.abs($('#timeline').width() - $(window).width() + rightStart) * m_zoomScale;
    rightSide = rightSide + 1000;

    $('#timeline').animate({ 'left': '-' + rightSide + 'px' }, 500, function ()
    {

    });
```

Is there something obvious I miss?
- m_zoomScale is set to 0.6
- There are about 70 Events on the timeline (so in essence it can scroll/drag to the far right until the last event is reached)

Here is a screenshot of the timeline just to get a rough idea:
http://tinypic.com/r/2i40zq/8